# Developing a windows service to communicate between a SQL server database and web service

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, windows-services

We have developed an iPhone application which communicates with SQL server database via asp.net hosted on a public server. We have completed all the development and we need to test this with live server data.

Now we understand that live server database is using dynamic ports and cannot be accessed from our asp.net script. Database administrator is against changing the dynamic ports as they are worried about the security threat. We tried asking them to change this by giving access to the  server where we host the asp.net web service but they are not willing to do this.

The solution they are asking is to develop a windows service which would act as a middleware between their SQL server database and our web service. They are ready to open ports for running that windows service on their server. Our iphone app need to take values from database as well as insert values to the databse.

We need to know if this is feasible to develop a windows service and if yes, can someone can guide us how to develop this?

Their server is running windows 2003 and SQL server version is 2008

Comment: Using the windows service is just the architecture I would recommend in the frst place. You should never give direct access to a production database out directly.

Comment: @JensH we do not have enough experience in developing this.. Can you guide us to some reference links for developing this?

Answer (score 0):

this are good reads on how to start creating a window service

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.80).aspx

http://tech.pro/tutorial/895/creating-a-simple-windows-service-in-csharp

Comment: These links go nowhere